# cygwin putty Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment

Tags: x11, cygwin, putty

When I start cygwin/X X Server (1.17.1-2) and then putty with x11 forwarding enabled (X display location set to `localhost:10.0` and MIT-Magic-Cookie-1 ticked) I still get the error

```
    Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

when I try to start any program (e.g. pycharm). Neither on my windows machine, nor on my linux box I have the `DISPLAY` variable set. When I hover over the cygwin icon in the tray on windows, it shows `cygwin x server :0.0`, so I tried both `export DISPLAY=:0.0` on my windows and linux machine. But then I get

```
Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:128)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:155)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:94)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:75)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations (`DISPLAY=:0`) removing the `X display location` in putty but doesnt help

setup:

- The linux box is a `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)`
- Windows is Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
- Putty is version 0.68 release Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 / MSVC++ 14.0 (_MSC_VER=1900)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start startxwin with the option `-listen` .
For example my shortcut is :

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; exec /usr/bin/startxwin -- -listen tcp"
```

https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-04/msg00050.html

> '-nolisten tcp' is now the default, so the server only accepts local connections on a unix domain socket. A '-listen' option has been
>   added which can be used to restore the previous behaviour.

Comment: I set `-listen tcp` in xlaunch config (as recommended here https://blog.woopi.org/wordpress/?p=293) but when I start putty after cygwin, just enable X11 forwarding (no X-display location) and connect to the linux server it still tells me `Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment`. Do I need to set the `DISPLAY` variable (I tried some combinations like `:0` and `:10` but that just results in `java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using...`

Comment: DISPLAY=:0 works on the same computer. You need to add the IP address for connection from a different one DISPLAY=your_cygwin_ip:0